# Register OnMouseOver-Event from CodeBehind?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I wan't to register the OnMouseOver and OnMouseOut-Event for an Image from the Code behind, because I must different if the user is logged in or not.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add an attribute to the object.

e.g.

```
 Image img = new Image();
 img.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "myjavascriptfunction();");
```

To set the paramater based on the id of the object, using this:

```
 Image img = new Image();
 img.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "myjavascriptfunction(" + img.ClientID + ");");
```

Comment: I must add the parameter of the image-id in the function, so "function(img123)", but because of the runat=Server the ID changes at runtime, what to do?

Comment: Edited to add what you require.

Answer (score 1):

Using ck's example, you can achieve what you're trying to do using the `ClientID` property on your server control. Like this:

```
yourImage.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "jsfunction(" + yourImage.ClientID + ");");
```

Answer (score 0):

On solution would be to use a css class and jQuery:

```
  <img id="generatedId" class="myHoverImage" />
```

javascript:

```
$("img.myHoverImage").mouseover ( function() {

  // you can access the generated id:      

  alert ( this.id );

  // --> your code goes here <-- \\      

});
```